# Travelling to Latin America to take hallucinogenic drugs: how does one do it safely?

Tags: health, local-customs, peru, drugs

Prompted by this...

> Thousands of international backpackers are flocking to the Peruvian
>   Amazon rainforest to drink ayahuasca tea, a plant mixture made by
>   shamans and taken as part of a spiritual ritual. Those who drink the
>   thick rich liquid often throw up, but then experience hours of
>   mind-altering visions and a sense of internal exploration.

Source: [Global Travel Industry News](http://www.eturbonews.com/36754/peru-tourism-more-powerful-lsd-and-hours-mind-altering-visions)

I am informed that there is a burgeoning tourist market in Peru and Brazil [for consuming hallucinogenic drugs](http://edition.cnn.com/2014/10/22/health/ayahuasca-medicine-six-things/), namely [Ayahuasca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayahuasca). This drug reportedly will mitigate the effects of post traumatic stress disorder and similar psychological problems.

This drug is legal in Peru and Brazil, and there are a number "operators" who "administer" the drug.

> But in South America ayahuasca is an integral part of some tribal
>   societies. In 2008, Peru's government recognised ayahuasca's status,
>   stating that it was "one of the basic pillars of the identity of the
>   Amazon peoples".

Source: [BBC News](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-27203322)

However, there are dangers involved...

> British student Henry Miller, 19, died in Colombia after apparently
>   consuming the traditional hallucinogenic drink ayahuasca, or yage.
>   Emma Thelwell, who took the drug herself, explains why it has become a
>   rite of passage for some backpackers.

This question is about selecting a "operator" (or 'shaman' to be precise). Are there licensing standards that govern who can supply and administer hallucinogens? Or how would one distinguish a legitimate operator from a bogus operator who might provide an impure product or otherwise rip you off?

Also, for planning purposes, after consuming the drug, how long before you regain coherence and can safely resume your travels?

Comment: Nice site to visit before taking DMT: [Erowid](https://www.erowid.org/chemicals/dmt/dmt.shtml). Some previous experience with [Psychonautics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychonautics) is advisable. Also [the setting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_and_setting) is very important, as *DMT* will [make You die](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ego_death) you have to absolutely trust the persons around you or it may trigger a bad trip. If you get scared, think about the beauty; if you get lost, remember the loved ones; Never follow yourself, just let it go. Have a nice journey, it's worth it :)

Comment: @MargaretBloom, wow, that could be an answer!  Is there a chance of getting lost in the jungle?

Comment: I actually wanted to say: Lost within your mind :) Anyway unless you are a total irresponsible person, you will be fine (and safe). Mostly you'll sleep and listen. Just think about possible situations before, e.g. have something to drink, something to make calls with, someone to talk to.

Comment: @MargaretBloom consider adding an answer

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your best bet would likely be to **go to Brazil and join a church ceremony**.  Ayahuasca is [legal there for religious use](https://www.erowid.org/chemicals/ayahuasca/ayahuasca_law6.shtml), and there are several well-established churches that use it regularly with a track record of not killing their members, most notably [Santo Daime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santo_Daime) and [União do Vegetal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uni%C3%A3o_do_Vegetal).

Church ceremonies (and the effects of ayahuasca) [can last up to 12 hours](http://santodaime.com/en/asks/#36), and you'll likely want a good night's sleep afterwards.

Interestingly, both have branches in the US and Europe which have (at least in some countries) been granted the right to [conduct ayahuasca ceremonies legally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayahuasca#Legal_status), so you may not even need to travel to Brazil to have a legal and authentic experience.

Obvious caveat: joining a church and professing to share their beliefs when you just want to try their <s>drugs</s> sacraments is morally, ethically and possibly even legally dubious.

Comment: Are they Christian churches? or some local religion?

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis They're loosely Christian (SD more, UDV less), but obviously with heavy animist/shamanist influence.

Comment: I do not think animist/shamanist  is close to Islam :/ so there's no way for me.. thanks :)

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis I doubt hallucinogens are compatible with Quran 5:90, regardless of the theological wrappings used...  although of course both argue that ayahuasca is not an intoxicant, but an entheogen: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entheogen

Comment: Mister, you are such a killjoy :) anyway 5:90 is talking about alcohol, not sure if Ayahuasca is considered alcohol ;)

Comment: Good answer, but it would be nice to have a step-by-step guide with contact information and pricing for *religious* aficionados :)

Comment: @Heidel Actually it talks about "intoxicants" not alcohol. While alcohol is certainly a rather popular intoxicant, there are many others and the term does include drugs.

Comment: "and possibly even legally dubious" - Expand?

Comment: @Insane: if there's legislation granting a special exception for religious use of an otherwise-illegal drug, which jpatokal is saying is the case in Brazil and some parts of the US and/or Europe, then using the drug when you in fact are *not* a believer in the religion, but are only falsely claiming to be, is possibly illegal.

Comment: @SteveJessop Good point, but it's not very easy to prove someone doesn't believe in something. I could just be a very laid back <religion> and not follow typical <religion> rules. Actually, it's kinda impossible.

Comment: @Insane: in the UK for example there's a specific exemption permitting Sikhs not to wear motorcycle helmets (which are otherwise required by law). Courts don't seem to have that much difficulty deciding whether someone is a Sikh or not ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop Common sense doctrine :)

Comment: @Insane In U.S. jurisprudence, generally only "sincerely-held religious beliefs" are considered to be protected. For example, a federal judge recently denied a Nebraska inmate's request to have his 'pastafarian' beliefs accommodated, as 'pastafarianism' is obviously satire and not a set of sincerely-held religious beliefs.

Comment: @reirab Right, yeah I don't doubt that

Comment: @voo the literal translation is more like "booze", and not intoxicants. This is one problem of the Quran translations, it is different and totally depends on the interpretation of the translator.

Comment: @Heidel That's the nice thing about religious texts, everyone can interpret them just the way they want. All the translations I can find on the internet refer to it as intoxicants though - which one are you using?

Comment: @voo I am an Arab, I can read it directly.

Answer (score 5):

Opposite to @jpatokal answer, I'd say that you can do it safely on Iquitos-Perú, where a lot of people often go to do this "*ceremonies*" and there are a lot of places that offers this service, for example [this](http://www.amazonexplorer.com/new/english/shamanismo/ayahuasca.htm).

The price is around 100$ per person per day (It's a pack that goes from 2 days to 8 days, depending on where you go to do it). For further information about the ceremony and recommendation [here](http://awkipuma.com/en/aya/sesiones.html)

And about which how to find trusty sites to do this, I'd highly recommend you 2 options:

Search on internet sites with a good recommendations like [this](http://www.manitiexpeditions.com/programs/ayahuasca/) or just go to the city (Iquitos) and ask the locals, they usually know which sites are the best, since they live there, and I can vouch that the people there is usually kind and helpfull.

Comment: +1, how do you vouch for the people with such confidence though?

Comment: I'm from Perú, and I have many friends that traveled to Iquitos so I have many good references.
Also, It's well known that the people from there are very cheerful and kind.