# Which nations have specific laws that allow/ disallow ENTRY of shamanic ritual plants/ herbs such as Ayahuasca?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal, religion, officials, drugs

[Travelling to Latin America to take hallucinogenic drugs: how does one do it safely?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67567/travelling-to-latin-america-to-take-hallucinogenic-drugs-how-does-one-do-it-saf)

This is a related question, but [objective here is different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayahuasca#Legal_status).

I have a few friends from Latin & Eastern European descent that are serious practitioners of Shamanic rituals and healings.

I've been meditating for several years and was curious about participating with them when we meet somewhere (**elsewhere in Latin America or SE Asia - outside of their country where they pratice; Mexico & Peru**) for a yoga reunion.

**Note:** I do not even consume alcohol or smoke or have ever thought of indulging in marijuana. But, I am genuinely curious about this.

I am curious about the [legality & laws at Point of Entry/ Exit and/ or inside other nations if they carried/ traveled with these/ such](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayahuasca#Legal_status) **[plants or their derivatives](http://www.shamanicjourney.com/plants-used-by-shamans)** to our reunion location (still open).

Which nations would be a YES, NO, MAYBE YES, MAYBE NOT to this? I do understand we must err on the side of caution, but I am curious to know if at all Latin & SE Asian nations have "laws" or "practices" around such?

Wouldnt it make sense to have a Wiki of such such type here:

[Which Schengen countries have bilateral agreements which ignore the standard 90/180 rule?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69255/which-schengen-countries-have-bilateral-agreements-which-ignore-the-standard-90)

Comment: Are you asking us to prepare a list?

Comment: @GayotFow - There is very little knowledge on this, but some indication of Nations which are for/ against or which do not care for, would be nice. Doesnt have to be a comprehensive one, but Indicative if possible like the answer to the linked Question

Comment: It's hard for us to prepare a list because the site is not set up for a collaborative effort. We're just individuals and nobody would get all of them. Your best bet is to prepare the best answer you can and add it as a 'wiki' entry. Community members can update it as they see fit. Marking your question as 'too broad'. Please try to follow the site format, use a wiki answer or etc. Thanks and all the best!

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69255/which-schengen-countries-have-bilateral-agreements-which-ignore-the-standard-90 - Like this.. Sure. How do I change it to a Wiki? It will good to be updated as well as information in case anyone needs

Comment: How do I convert it to a Wiki? Can you do it?

Comment: Yeah dude, that's a 'wiki' question/answer.  When you put in your answer, check the 'Wiki' checkbox. :)

Comment: Note that he put the question and answer in simultaneously and wiki'd it immediately :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the information on, [Travelling to Latin America to take hallucinogenic drugs: how does one do it safely?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67567/travelling-to-latin-america-to-take-hallucinogenic-drugs-how-does-one-do-it-saf)

Peru and Brazil allow such usage, but it's not clear on their Import & Export laws. US courts have allowed limited religious usage to certain followers of such faiths, but entry & exits have examples of people being arrested by BCP (as was in the case of a Colombian Shamanic healer).

I have friends in the Mexico City area who also follow similar rituals.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayahuasca#Legal_status

This was the first source of information on legalities across places which have not explicitly allow or legalized it for general or specific purposes.

> Internationally, DMT is a Schedule I drug under the Convention on Psychotropic Substances. The Commentary on the Convention on Psychotropic Substances notes, however, that the plants containing it are not subject to international control:[45]

*The cultivation of plants from which psychotropic substances are obtained is not controlled by the Vienna Convention. . . . Neither the crown (fruit, mescal button) of the Peyote cactus nor the roots of the plant Mimosa hostilis nor Psilocybe mushrooms themselves are included in Schedule 1, but only their respective principals, mescaline, DMT, and psilocin.*

A fax from the Secretary of the International Narcotics Control Board (INCB) to the Netherlands Ministry of Public Health sent in 2001 goes on to state that "Consequently, preparations (e.g. decoctions) made of these plants, including ayahuasca, **are not under international control and, therefore, not subject to any of the articles of the 1971 Convention**."[46]

Despite the **INCB's 2001 affirmation that ayahuasca is not subject to drug control by international convention**, in its **2010 Annual Report** the **Board recommended that governments consider controlling (i.e. criminalizing) ayahuasca at the national level**. This recommendation by the INCB has been **criticized as an attempt by the Board to overstep its legitimate mandate** and as establishing a reason for governments to **violate the human rights (i.e., religious freedom) of ceremonial ayahuasca drinkers**.[47]

It would be interesting and key to research the specifics of Nations and their viewpoints / approaches to such.